# References for estimating lifetime earnings lost due to caregiving (health economics)

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, productivity, empirical-methods

I am working on a project on the productivity costs for caregivers of people with Disease X, a degenerative disease that affects mobility over time.  I am looking for references, either scholarly articles or textbooks, on estimating lifetime labor market earnings lost for caregivers of these patients.  What are some recommended or "essential" reading in this methodology?